# Run a command line tool as part of build process

Tags: go, build, sublimetext3

I'm just getting started with Go, and also thought I'd learn Sublime Text while I was at it.

I've installed the official [Go Build package for Sublime](https://github.com/golang/sublime-build) and got everything building nicely. But my little project relies on binary resources, so I'm using [go-bindata](https://github.com/jteeuwen/go-bindata) to build my files directly into my executable.

What I need help with is the fact I don't know how to add the command line call to go-bindata to the build processes provided by Go Build. Ideally I'd like to simply run the command before the build process starts.

I'm working on Windows 10, if that's important info.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually this is done with [`go generate`](https://blog.golang.org/generate). Although the Sublime3 bundle does **not** support this.

In one of your files add something like this into as the top comment:

```
//go:generate go-bindata data/
```

Now you can bundle and bundle your project with `go generate` and then `go build`.

This works on all platforms that are supported by Go.

If really need a one command does everything thing: Use a Makefile or a batch script and use that as your build command in Sublime.

Comment: Thank you! This is even better than what I thought I wanted.